# Printing the nonempty portion of a circular dequeue

Tags: python, list, deque, circular-list, arraydeque

Consider the dequeue=[2, 3, 4, None, None, None, 1]. It is circular and has suppose that 1 is the front of the dequeue and 4 is the back of the dequeue, knock on wood, we should have these indices stored under the variables front and back, their values being 6 and 2, respectively.

How can I print the values between the indices front and back, that is, [1, 2, 3, 4]. Better yet, and more specifically, I was hoping to find a way to make a string that would more specifically look like [ 1, 2, 3, 4]. My code is as follows, but I don't believe it is time efficient and, moreover, within the larger chunk of my code, I'm not sure this method is working.

def str(self):

```
if self.size==0:       #my first thoughts are to simply catch an empty dequeue
    return "[ ]"

elif self.size==1:      #same for a dequeue of only one object.
    string = "[ "+str(self.__contents[0])+" ]"
    return string

else:
    string="[ "
    index=self.front
    while (index%self.capacity) != self.back:
        string = string + str(self.contents[index]) + ", "
        index+=1
    string=string+str(self.__contents[self.back]) + " ]"
    return string
```

Where self.size=the number of nonempty entries, self.capacity=the total number of cells in the array, self.contents representing the contents of the array, and self.front and self.back representing the indices of the front and back of the dequeue.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to use the built-in [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque)? If so, it supports standard iteration making a list comprehension quite pythonic:

```
'[{}]'.format(', '.join(x for x in my_deque if x is not None)
```

If it is not a built-in `deque`, why not add iteration support to your type to allow the above method (and probably many other methods).

Comment: Generally, I don't like using built in features. Even though it helps a lot, I feel like it kind of cheats some of purpose of a project that I'm supposed to learn from. Anyhow, though, thanks for you answer. I actually solved my problem earlier this morning, in future I hope to make use out of the built in deque tho!